# How prevalent are multisigs?

Tags: multi-signature

There seemed to be great demand for multi-siganture transactions to be provided, but they don't seem to be so popular now that they are available.

What percentage of transactions are multisig since their release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the stats of different transaction types here: http://webbtc.com/stats